# Find the word and copy paste the value in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have excelled file of many countries where I have to get the word (Which is in column A) and then copy the % of that word (15% which is in column I) and paste it in some other sheet.

I want to find windows 8 and windows tablet from first sheet and paste in second sheet.

I took a macro from the Shiddarth rout blog which helps in finding the word. I have copied the same below. But I need to copy and paste the percentage in another excel sheet after finding the word. Can you please help me with this.

For Ex: [image]
[image]

```
Sub Sample1()
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
t = GetTickCount
On Error GoTo Err
Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
lastRow = oSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
strSearch = "Windows 8"
Set aCell = oSht.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Value Found in Cell " & aCell.Address & vbCrLf & _
"and it took " & GetTickCount - t & "milliseconds"
End If
Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm slightly confused by the way you pose your question, but I believe I can help you out.

aCell will have properties of .Row and .Column for specifically referencing the data, but also useful when pulling cell values from the same row or column.

Using the Range.Copy method will probably be easiest for you.

```
aCell.Copy destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

or

```
aCell.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

You can then decide where you would like to paste the values. As I reread your question, it seems like you want to find that value, and then copy the value in another column. Then you would use.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & aCell.Row).Copy destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for.Thank you very much for your help on this